# "spirit of the law" VS "spirit of the laws" VS "spirit of law"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, zero-article

> 1. we should uphold the **spirit of the laws** to build a society based on the rule of law.
> 2. we should uphold the **spirit of the law** to build a society based on the rule of law.
> 3. we should uphold the **spirit of law** to build a society based on the rule of law.

In this context, which one is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The well-established collocation is "the spirit of the law".